# Python check if int is in certain object of list

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement

i currently have a result set with the following data:

```
((0L, datetime.date(2018, 1, 29)), (0L, datetime.date(2018, 1, 30)), (0L, 
datetime.date(2018, 1, 31)), (0L, datetime.date(2018, 2, 1)))
```

I am trying to check if the current date has the status 0 or 1.

Currently i do this:

```
   if checkdate():
        if result_set[0] == 1:
```

The checkdate function checks if the currentdate is inside the list somewhere.
But there i'm stuck trying to figure out if that date has the status 1 or 0. The status is the first item on the list (0l and 1L) mysql somehow adds a L after the 0 and 1.

Currently my checkdate function looks like this:

`return any(d[1] == cd for d in result_set)`

Would love some help!

---

Edit: Now, `checkdate` looks like this:

`return next(((s,d) for (s,d) in dates if d == date), None)`

```
entry = checkdate([x[1] for x in result_set], cd)
            if entry is not None:
```

Comment: Can you define what do you mean by `status 0 or 1` ?

Comment: Yes my bad, the first result in the lists (0L and 1L) is supposed to be the status. in my database this is either 0 or 1. MySQL adds a L for some reason.

Comment: Change function `checkdate` to return the index of the current date in the list, or -1 if it is not in the list. Then you can simply do something like `index = checkdate(); if index >= 0 and result_set[index][0] == 1: ...`.

Comment: @goodvibration That sounds good. How would i do this? My current checkdate function is the following: return any(d[1] == cd for d in result_set)

Comment: You probably should redesign the data, and use a dictionary that maps `date` objects to `int`s.

Comment: Please don't remove/alter your original code when editing your question. You can (and should) add updates to your code, but not remove the original code, or any answers written for that code will be invalidated or look like they just copied the code that you already have. I fixed that for now.

Comment: @tobias_k I'm sorry! thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your `checkdate` function to return the actual `(status, date)` pair instead of just whether such a pair exists. For this, you can translate your `any` expression almost 1:1 into a `next` statement, using `None` as the default in case no such pair exists.

For example, like this (I also changed the function to take parameters instead of using global variables, but that's not essential for this to work).

```
import datetime
result_set = ((0, datetime.date(2018, 1, 29)), (1, datetime.date(2018, 1, 30)),   
              (0, datetime.date(2018, 1, 31)), (0, datetime.date(2018, 2, 1)))
cd = datetime.date(2018, 1, 30)

def checkdate(dates, date):
    return next(((s, d) for (s, d) in dates if d == date), None)

entry = checkdate(result_set, cd)
if entry is not None and entry[0] == 1:
    print("found")
```

Or like this, if you prefer using the global `result_set` and `cd` variables:

```
def checkdate():
    return next(((s, d) for (s, d) in result_set if d == cd), None)

entry = checkdate()
if entry is not None and entry[0] == 1:
    print("found")
```

Comment: Trying this i get the following error: datetime.date is not iterable

Comment: @WesleyvanStraalen I just saw your edit. You should pass the list of `(status, date)` pairs to `checkdate`, not just the dates as you seem to do.

Answer (score 0):

Change function `checkdate` to return the index of the current date in the list, or -1 if it is not there.

Then you can simply do something like:

```
index = checkdate()
if index >= 0 and result_set[index][0] == 1:
    ...
```

Comment: Why not return the tuple itself or `None`?

Comment: Seems nice, how would i make the function return the index?

Comment: @hjpotter92: That's also an option (and probably not the only one).

Comment: @WesleyvanStraalen: How about iterating the list?